# Nodejs server works on localhost but not on real server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm setting up a server for an application and I need to accept requests sent to the server.
Everything works fine when running node on localhost, but when I run the code on my company website, it won't respond.

Maybe it has something to do with the address because when I run in localhost it's "http://localhost:3000/".
But when I run on the company server it's "http://company.com:3000/app/".

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send("Hello");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Is port 3000 open on the server? Either try to open it or changing the port to 80 which is a default and most likely enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you run on port 3000 on both localhost and server, and you want to get all the requests from `/app` on the deployment server, you need to change your `app.get()` accordingly.

```
app.get('/app', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Hello");
});
```

Comment: already tried that but doesn't seem to work, app is the directory on the server where I'm running node

Comment: @kristiankeller It doesn't matter what directory the server is running in. This has nothing to do with a web-root. Your service should be available at the port you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a firewall setup on your server?
Have you tried opening the port on your server? 
If the port is closed the server won't be able to serve the content "outside" the local interface.

You can also try creating a reverse-proxy if you don't want to open that port, meaning that the webserver will take the content from the process listening on port 3000 and redirect it to a designated port (that can be 80 or 443, for instance).